# Search database for cell that contains all of the specified characters but no others

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm attempting to write a small API for my internal use that basically searches my table column for all results that contain specified letters but ignores cells that contain more letters than specified.

For example, let's say I have the following rows:

```
| id | word   |
| 1  | cloud  |
| 2  | could  |
| 3  | cloudy |
```

And my user inputs the string "dulco". In this example, we search the database for a cell that contains all of the letters supplied, but no extras. So every word would be a positive match, except "cloudy" because it has an extra letter. Now just imagine this on a much bigger scale, where there are over 100 thousand rows.

I've done a bit of searching trying to figure out how to do this, but I can't figure out the proper search terms, and thus I can't figure out how to do the search. I thought of something like a LIKE clause:

```
$query = "SELECT word FROM words WHERE word LIKE '%d%u%l%c%o%'";
```

but this wouldn't work properly because there may be other letters there too, meaning the selection would be invalid.

Is this type of query possible, and if so, how can I do such a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this using a combination of `INSTR` and `LENGTH` :

```
SELECT word FROM words 
WHERE INSTR(word,"d") 
  AND INSTR(word,"u") 
  AND INSTR(word,"l") 
  AND INSTR(word,"c") 
  AND INSTR(word,"o") 
  AND LENGTH(word)=5;
```

Where 5 is the length of input string.

Outputs :

```
+-------+
| word  |
+-------+
| cloud |
| could |
+-------+
```

---

**Edit** for multiple occurences of the same letter :

```
SELECT word FROM words  
 WHERE LOCATE("y",word) 
   AND LOCATE("e",word)
   AND LOCATE("l",word)
   AND LOCATE("l",word, LOCATE("l",word)+1)
   AND LENGTH(word)=4;
```

So, if the table contains `yell` and `yella`, it will returns only `yell`.

This must be preprocessed by PHP to get the required query, ONLY for multiple occurences of the same letter.

Comment: This works for me, and is also _very_ fast. All I had to do was make a little foreach loop that generates the query for me [like this](https://eval.in/950958).

Comment: I've just found a fault with this, it does not work as expected for words that contain multiple of a single letter. For example, the word "yell". This allows the query to return words that have 1 extra character in them

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Humm.. Interesting. Did you find a solution? I'll search another anwser.

Comment: I have not found another solution. I have a sort of workaround currently by looping through the result sets with PHP and checking if there are any foreign letters.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I've update the anwser. Could you please check if it could be a solution for you?

Comment: That will probably work, I just think my post-processing in PHP works better. It would be pretty annoying having to do a check for this before the query

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I'm agree :)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a function called **RegExP**. So, in theory, you can query, and filter elements using a regular expression.

```
$query = "SELECT word FROM words WHERE word REGEXP '^[dulco]{5}$'";
```

The only thing is you should consider how expensive this query could be.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton the regular expression is the key. The previous one was incorrect. Try this new way. I think this expression is much easier to build than a complex query doing a split for the string. I'm terrible with Regular Expressions.

Comment: Yes I believe this way will likely work, the question really becomes which one is faster. The other answer provided me a pretty fast result, I will test with the regex shortly.

Comment: This sort of works, but not exactly, because of the same reason as before. The regex checks if any of the characters exist, and returns all 5 letter words that contain at least 1 of the letters. For example, searching the word "able" should result in the response: `["able","albe","bael","bale","blae"]`, but with your regex it returns: `["abba","abbe","able","alae","albe","alee","baal","baba","babe","bael","bale","ball","bell","blab","blae","bleb","blee","leal"]`.